# Menu items grayed out using split view controller - Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

I'm working to bring my iPad app to the Mac using Catalyst. My app uses a split view controller. The master view controller has two rows that can be tapped that let a user take a photo or select a photo from the camera roll.
I am trying to add two menu items with keyboard shortcuts for each of these actions.

After adding the menu items following the steps in a WWDC video, the menu items are grayed out when the app first launches. Below is a screenshot showing the app first launched and Take Photo and Select From Camera Roll are both grayed out.
[image: Grayed out menu items]

However, if I toggle/tap any item in the master view controller, the menu items become enabled and work as intended. Once I select a menu item, it goes back to being grayed out and I need to toggle/tap an item in the master view controller to make them enabled again.
[image: enabled menu items]

I can't figure out why the items are being grayed out. I'm thinking it may be related to the split view controller but have not been able to figure anything out.

The code I'm using to add the menu items is pretty simple. I added `@IBAction` to the methods that take a photo and select from the camera roll. I added a Main Menu to my Storyboard file with two new Inline Menu items and connected each to to the methods.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue.  I'm experiencing the same issue.  The UIKeyCommand is only enabled if the master view controller is in the responder chain, and not the detail view controller.  "Auto Enables Items" appears to be OK for NSMenu, but perhaps not for UIMenu?

Comment: Fwiw I'm seeing this exact same issue, where the Menu items don't become enabled until I've interacted with the app. I'm using Xcode 11.4 beta 3.

And I'm seeing the same issue in Apple's sample app here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicommand/adding_menus_and_shortcuts_to_the_menu_bar_and_user_interface

Comment: overriding `canBecomeFirstResponder` in the controller has helped to enable the menu commands initially, but still having the problem when another controller is clicked and thus not in the responder chain anymore

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I mixed it up. This is only valid for a macOS but not for a Catalyst app !!!.

For Catalyst the best way is to use a menu builder and related functionality.

------ Ignore this if its about Catalyst -------

Did you try switch off "Auto Enables Items" for the menu.
If this will not help or you want to control activation I would follow the documentation from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html) or try with something like below in your view controller.

```
 override func validate(_ command: UICommand) {

      switch command.action {
      case #selector(doSomething):

          command.title = "Change the title"
          command.attributes = [.disabled]
            // command.attributes = []

        default:
        break
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see "Auto Enable Items" in Xcode. I'm running Xcode 11. What version are you running?

Comment: You will get it in any version of Xcode. I am using the latest. It’s the menu not the menu item which is selected in the screenshot.

Comment: You are right. I mixed it up :-(.  For Catalyst apps especially with SwiftUI the best approach would be to use menu builder functionality. Of corse you can also add a Storyboard to your SwiftUI Catalyst app but I was not able to get any menu validation functionality this way.

Comment: I'm seeing validate being called in AppDelegate but not in a view controller. In the same view controller where I want it to be called, canPerformAction IS being called. I want validate to be called in the VC because the details that determine if a menu should be greyed out are private variables to the VC.

Hmmm - I think I just needed to add self.becomeFirtResponder() to the VC. Not sure if that is the right approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a perhaps related problem in my Catalyst app.

I'm using menu the menu-builder method, but I find that the app will request a menu for one view controller but try to validate it against another view controller. I presume that this is because I have two view controllers presiding over parts of the same screen.

The workaround I used is to handle queries for one view controller's menu items in the other view controller. For example, let's say you have controllers sharing the screen, called

- MainVC
- PlayViewController

The app will call the menu builder for MainVC, but you want to have some hotkeys that call PlaybackVC methods. So you populate the Playback menu with an item that calls PlayViewController.nextClip(), for example.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class func playbackMenu() -> UIMenu
{
let prevCmd =
    UIKeyCommand(title: "Previous clip",
                 image: nil,
                 action: #selector(PlayViewController.cmdPrevClip(_:)),
                 input: UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow,
                 modifierFlags: .control,
                 propertyList: nil)

let nextCmd =
    UIKeyCommand(title: "Next clip",
                 image: nil,
                 action: #selector(PlayViewController.cmdNextClip(_:)),
                 input: UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow,
                 modifierFlags: .control,
                 propertyList: nil)

let loopCmd =
    UIKeyCommand(title: "Loop",
                 image: nil,
                 action: #selector(PlayViewController.cmdToggleLoopClip(_:)),
                 input: "L",
                 modifierFlags: .control,
                 propertyList: nil)
let theMenu =
    UIMenu(title: "Playback",
           image: nil,
           identifier: UIMenu.Identifier("com.atomos.AtomRemoteMenus.playbackMenu"),
           options: .destructive,
           children: [prevCmd, nextCmd, loopCmd])

return theMenu
}
```

Later, when the OS asks **MainVC** to validate items in the Playback menu, **MainVC's** *canPerformAction()* method needs to handle it like so:

```
else if action == #selector(PlayViewController.cmdNextClip(_:))
{
    if m_playController != nil
    {
        return m_playController!.canPerformAction(#selector(PlayViewController.cmdNextClip(_:)), withSender: sender)
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

So yes I have a redundant canPerformAction method in PlayViewController because I don't know if it might someday be called.

You might think hey, I'll just make stub methods in MainVC and put calls to those in the Playback menu, and in turn call the PlayViewController's methods. Nope, because each menu item's command targets what it thinks the active view controller is at any given point... which wasn't MainVC in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by using a custom subclass of UISplitViewController which:

1. Overrides `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)` .  This function checks with both its master view controller AND its details view controller if they can handle the action, and returns the result.
2. Includes a stub @IBAction for every menu command (yes, painful!) that then passes it off to the appropriate child view controller.

This is my implementation:

```
class CustomSplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    
    enum MasterDetail: Int {
        case master = 0
        case detail = 1
    }
    
    func child(ofType type: MasterDetail) -> UIViewController? {
        let childTypeIndex = type.rawValue > viewControllers.count - 1 ? 0 : type.rawValue
        if let navController = viewControllers[childTypeIndex] as? UINavigationController {
            if let viewController = navController.topViewController {
                if viewController.navigationController?.visibleViewController == viewController {
                    return viewController
                }
            }
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return child(ofType: .master)?.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) ?? child(ofType: .detail)?.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender) ?? false
    }
    
    @IBAction func someMasterControllerAction(_ sender: Any?) {
        (child(ofType: .master) as? MasterController)?. someMasterControllerAction(sender)
    }
    
    @IBAction func someDetailControllerAction(_ sender: Any?) {
        (child(ofType: .detail) as? MasterController)?. someDetailControllerAction(sender)
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```